# how to replace in csv file using nodejs

Tags: node.js, replace

how could I replace character in the following csv file using nodejs ?

```
{"patient":{"_id":"0dc329fe4ac40d8640528025cb53bbdc"},"graphing":[]}
{"patient":{"_id":"0f107203d419496e855d1e92259883bc"},"graphing":[]}
{"patient":{"_id":"0f10be0663c34f62a82a5ac8331bea6a"},"graphing":[]}
```

the result I'd like to be is as follow:

```
[ {"patient":{"_id":"0dc329fe4ac40d8640528025cb53bbdc"},"graphing":[]}  ,

{"patient":{"_id":"0f107203d419496e855d1e92259883bc"},"graphing":[]} ,

{"patient":{"_id":"0f10be0663c34f62a82a5ac8331bea6a"},"graphing":[]} ]
```

In the beginning of line, add [ and end of the line  add ,.

In the last line, just add ].

Thanks for assist

Comment: Both original and expected are same.What you need exactly??

Comment: That doesn't look like CSV

Comment: This looks like a new line json (ndjson) not csv. You can parse a new line json using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ndjson. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at using regex replacement

```
str = str.replace(/(^{*)/, "[{")
str = str.replace(/(}$)/, "},")
str = str.slice(0, -1) + ']';
```